# QT Background-Image

Tags: c++, qt, background, designer, qwidget

I tried to add a gradient background on my main QWidget by adding (background-image:url(images/background.png) to its stylesheet but I noticed HUGE performance drops and I haven't written any code yet.

background image is a gradient , 16bit 1x800 px png.

So my question is, how can I add a nice gradient to my QWidgets / QFrames without slowing down the program? Using only the designer.

Comment: Where did you note the performance drop: within Designer, or after you compile and run designer-generated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QPalette thePalette = this->palette();
QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, 50);
gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(227,177,27));
gradient.setColorAt(0.25, QColor(170,177,167));

gradient.setColorAt(1, Qt::white);
QBrush brush(gradient);
thePalette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, brush);
setPalette(thePalette);
```

and modify freely the colors and the positions. Although that this is code, it might be useful.

Comment: Yes, do this instead. It's much, much nicer and whilst you can't do it in designer it's a really simple code change.